# Change player position at the starting of each level

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am making a platformer-type game in pygame. I want the player and the enemy co-ordinates to be different at the starting of each level, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Here's the code:

```py
import pygame
 
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
LIGHTRED = (191, 52, 52)
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500
 
class SpriteSheet(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height, colour):
        image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()
        image.set_colorkey(colour)
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image

class Skeleton(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player
        controls. """
 
    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor function """
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("enemy.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 64, 64, LIGHTRED)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, [32, 32])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
    
 
        # Set speed vector of player
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
 
        # List of sprites we can bump against
        self.level = None
 
    def update(self):
        """ Move the player. """
        # Gravity
        self.calc_grav()
 
        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
 
        # See if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right,
            # set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
 
        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
 
        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
 
            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
 
            # Stop our vertical movement
            self.change_y = 0
 
    def calc_grav(self):
        """ Calculate effect of gravity. """
        if self.change_y == 0:
            self.change_y = 1
        else:
            self.change_y += .47
        # See if we are on the ground.
        if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.change_y >= 0:
            self.change_y = 0
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height
 
    def jump(self):
        """ Called when user hits 'jump' button. """
 
        # move down a bit and see if there is a platform below us.
        # Move down 2 pixels because it doesn't work well if we only move down
        # 1 when working with a platform moving down.
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2
 
        # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.change_y = -10
 
    # Player-controlled movement:
    def go_left(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the left arrow. """
        self.change_x = 6
 
    def go_right(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the right arrow. """
        self.change_x = -6
 
    def stop(self):
        """ Called when the user lets off the keyboard. """
        self.change_x = 0
 
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player
        controls. """
 
    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor function """
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Player (1).png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 64, 64, BLACK)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, [32, 32])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
    
 
        # Set speed vector of player
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
 
        # List of sprites we can bump against
        self.level = None
 
    def update(self):
        """ Move the player. """
        # Gravity
        self.calc_grav()
 
        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
 
        # See if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right,
            # set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
 
        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
 
        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
 
            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
 
            # Stop our vertical movement
            self.change_y = 0
 
    def calc_grav(self):
        """ Calculate effect of gravity. """
        if self.change_y == 0:
            self.change_y = 1
        else:
            self.change_y += .47
        # See if we are on the ground.
        if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.change_y >= 0:
            self.change_y = 0
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height
 
    def jump(self):
        """ Called when user hits 'jump' button. """
 
        # move down a bit and see if there is a platform below us.
        # Move down 2 pixels because it doesn't work well if we only move down
        # 1 when working with a platform moving down.
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2
 
        # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.change_y = -10
 
    # Player-controlled movement:
    def go_left(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the left arrow. """
        self.change_x = -6
 
    def go_right(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the right arrow. """
        self.change_x = 6
 
    def stop(self):
        """ Called when the user lets off the keyboard. """
        self.change_x = 0
class Portal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("portal.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 100, 118, 197, BLACK)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, [72, 72])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ Platform the user can jump on """
 
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """ Platform constructor. Assumes constructed with user passing in
            an array of 5 numbers like what's defined at the top of this
            code. """
        super().__init__()
 
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
 
class Level(object):
    """ This is a generic super-class used to define a level.
        Create a child class for each level with level-specific
        info. """
 
    def __init__(self, skeleton, player):
        """ Constructor. Pass in a handle to player. Needed for when moving platforms
            collide with the player. """
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.skeleton = skeleton
        self.player = player
         
        # Background image
        self.background = None
 
    # Update everythign on this level
    def update(self):
        """ Update everything in this level."""
        self.platform_list.update()
        self.enemy_list.update()
 
    def draw(self, screen):
        """ Draw everything on this level. """
 
        # Draw all the sprite lists that we have
        self.platform_list.draw(screen)
        self.enemy_list.draw(screen)
 
 
# Create platforms for the level
class Level_01(Level):
    """ Definition for level 1. """
 
    def __init__(self, skeleton, player):
        """ Create level 1. """
 
        # Call the parent constructor
        Level.__init__(self, skeleton, player)
 
        # Array with width, height, x, and y of platform        
        level = [[59, 500, 0, 0],
                 [1000-59, 56, 59, 0],
                 [59, 500, 1000-59, 0],
                 [1000, 59, 0, 500-55],
                 [185, 56, 0, 278],
                 [3, 26, 185, 284],
                 [62, 59, 188, 278+56],
                 [55, 59*4+42, 317, 0],
                 [68, 56, 188+61, 59*3-10],
                 [62*4, 120, 317+60, 334],
                 [62*2+3, 56, 814, 278],
                 [62, 56, 750, 334],
                 [55, 56*3, 567, 56],
                 [62*2+2, 56, 622, 167],
                 [55, 56, 629, 223],
                 ]
        
 
        # Go through the array above and add platforms
        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.skeleton = self.skeleton
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)
class Level_02(Level):
    """ Definition for level 1. """
 
    def __init__(self, skeleton, player):
        """ Create level 1. """
 
        # Call the parent constructor
        Level.__init__(self, skeleton, player)
 
        # Array with width, height, x, and y of platform        
        level = [[59, 500, 0, 0],
                 [1000-59, 56, 59, 0],
                 [59, 500, 1000-59, 0],
                 [1000, 59, 0, 500-55],
                 [310, 56, 0, 167],
                 [130, 53, 817, 171],
                 [183, 50, 503, 395],
                 [58*4+13, 54, 378, 224],
                 [55, 56, 379, 278],
                 [58, 55, 690, 169],
                 ]
        
 
        # Go through the array above and add platforms
        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.skeleton = self.skeleton
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)
 
def main():
    """ Main Program """
    pygame.init()
 
    # Set the height and width of the screen
    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    
    lvl_2 = pygame.image.load("lvl_2.png")
    lvl_1 = pygame.image.load("lvl_1.png")
    level_list = []
    skeleton = Skeleton()
    player = Player()
    portal = Portal()
    level_list.append(Level_01(skeleton, player) )
    level_list.append(Level_02(skeleton, player) )
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
    lvl_2 = pygame.transform.scale(lvl_2, [1000, 500])
    lvl_1 = pygame.transform.scale(lvl_1, [1000, 500])
    pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer Jumper")
 
    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    portal_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    skeleton.level = current_level
    player.level = current_level
    skeleton.rect.x = 340
    skeleton.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - skeleton.rect.height - 50
    player.rect.x = 340
    player.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height-50
    portal.rect.x = 460
    portal.rect.y = 260
    active_sprite_list.add(skeleton)
    active_sprite_list.add(player)
    active_sprite_list.add(portal)
    portal_list.add(portal)
    player_list.add(player)

    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False
 
    # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print(event.pos)
 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    skeleton.go_left()
                    player.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    skeleton.go_right()
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    skeleton.jump()
                    player.jump()
                    
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and skeleton.change_x > 0:
                    skeleton.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and skeleton.change_x < 0:
                    skeleton.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
                    player.stop() 
        
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        if current_level_no == 0:
            screen.blit(lvl_1, [0, 0])
        if current_level_no == 1:
            screen.blit(lvl_2, [0, 0])
            portal.rect.x = 570
            portal.rect.y = 320
        
        #screen.blit(bg, [0, 0])
        active_sprite_list.update()
        if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(portal_list, player_list, False, False):
            
            current_level_no += 1
            print(current_level_no)
            current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
            player.level = current_level
            skeleton.level = current_level
         #Update items in the level
        current_level.update()
 
        # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
        if skeleton.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            skeleton.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
 
        # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
        if skeleton.rect.left < 0:
            skeleton.rect.left = 0
            
        if player.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            player.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
 
        # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
        if player.rect.left < 0:
            player.rect.left = 0
 
        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)
 
        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT
 
        # Limit to 60 frames per second
        clock.tick(60)
 
        # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        pygame.display.flip()
 
    # Be IDLE friendly. If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
    # on exit.
    pygame.quit()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can someone please help me?

(Also please don't read the comments I've written in the code, they're all messed up).

Comment: You can just set the start positions in the level and set player.rect.x = start_x and player.rect.y = start_y when you create the level. You would need to change it so it only created the level when needed though, not both at the start like now.

Comment: @marienbad If I do player.rect.x = start_x in the main loop, then the player will not be able to move because the x position will always be start_x.

Comment: Not in the main loop, in the level object.

Comment: @marienbad I added player.rect.x = 60 in the class Level_02, then I appended Level_02 to the list when current_level_no == 2, but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to set the player rect with the values in the level object, and do this for both level objects.  So in the level obj it should have start_x =  ... and start_y = ... Then when you make the player and start the level, set the player rect to those values.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say create a function in both the player and enemy class as follows:

```
def set_pos(self,x_pos, y_pos):
    self.rect.x = x_pos
    self.rect.y = y_pos
```

Then when defining a level do at the end of the init function (replacing the arguements with the positions you want in each level):

```
self.player.set_pos(desired_player_x, desired_player_y)
self.skeleton.set_pos(desired_skel_x, desired_skel_y)
```

As some additional advice, you might want to consider making a parent class for Skeleton and Player as `update`, `calc_grav`, and `stop` all seem to be the same, and you could call skeleton.go_right() rather than go_left() and vice versa in the update loop.

Also I think you could add in elif statements both here:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and skeleton.change_x > 0:
        skeleton.stop()
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and skeleton.change_x < 0:
        skeleton.stop()
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
        player.stop()
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
        player.stop()
```

and here:

```
if current_level_no == 0:
    screen.blit(lvl_1, [0, 0])
elif current_level_no == 1:
    screen.blit(lvl_2, [0, 0])
    portal.rect.x = 570
    portal.rect.y = 320
```